# cmd runner not working for jmeter 3.0

Tags: jmeter

I am converting jtl files to csv using cmd runner. I am using jmeter 3.0
I have placed all required files of cmd runner at lib/ext files.

after running below command,
java -jar cmdrunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv C:\Aggregate_Report.csv --input-jtl C:\a.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport

I am getting below error,

ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jme
er.vizualizers.AggregateReportGui

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

After many trial and error scenarios, I searched the workaround by myself.

cmd runner is not available in jmeter 3.0, you have to download it from jmeter 2.4, then place lib/extr folder to jmeter 3.0 folder. It is working for me.